# Error in creating Jenkins job to build a GITHUB project

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am creating a Jenkins job to run Jenkins build process by a GITHUB push. I have done the following - 
1) Install Jenkins on tomcat
2) Install GIT plugin
3) Create New job 
4) Choose GIT in source code management

When i enter public GITHUB repository URL. It shows an error --- "Failed to connect to repository : Error performing command: git ls-remote -h https://github.com/vippujain/devops_poc.git HEAD"

Feel free to write me if any further details require.

Comment: Can you try running the same command(from the log) on the command line & check if  lists the repository data ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your consideration!

I fix the problem and the fix is -

1) Install GIT on Jenkins server
Command used to install GIT on centos - `yum install git`

When you installed GIT plugin inside the Jenkins, it uses all git commands. This is the reason GIT need to be installed on server to run.